# Can a folder contain files from two different svn projects?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I currently have a single svn project for all work on a website. But I'd like to have a separate project in the same repo for a small app which forms part of that site so I can develop it separately.

At the moment there are some folders which contain a mix of files related only to the site and files related only to the app.

Will this work with svn?

(I'm using tortoisesvn and am working solo. I realise this may be a best development practice issue rather than svn.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subversion's external definitions. Check out the [docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html).

Comment: As it says, "... an externals definition can only point to directories, not files." I guess this does point towards me separating directories out.

Comment: @e100: I've updated the link to point to the most recent docs. It states: "Subversion 1.6 brings another improvement to externals definitions by introducing external definitions for files. File externals are configured just like externals for directories and appear as a versioned file in the working copy."

Comment: Ah, interesting. But I suspect it's going to be easier to manage if I do separate out. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this explanation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-common-projects.html) (svn:externals) will help you and does exactly what you need.